# SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am totally new to SharePoint and what I would like to do is get a list of every item in a specified list from a specified site as a DataSet. Where can I find examples, books, etc. for this? My test VM is SharePoint 2013 under Visual Studio 2010. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/2758e3f3-d603-4bb7-9733-25d34199cba3

> The SPListItemCollection class represents a collection of list items
>   (SPListItem instances) and is returned by either the Items property of
>   SPList, which returns the complete collection of list items, or by the
>   GetItems method of SPList described previously. SPListItemCollection
>   exposes a method called GetDataTable. This method returns an ADO.NET
>   DataTable object that has the same schema as the parent SharePoint
>   list and that is filled with the items of the SPListItemCollection
>   instance. You can add that datatable into Dataset for further use

Function to create a DataTable from a list:

```
private static DataTable ConvertSPListToDataTable(SPList oList)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        dt = oList.Items.GetDataTable();
        foreach(DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        c.ColumnName = System.Xml.XmlConvert.DecodeName(c.ColumnName);
        return (dt);
    }
    catch
    {
        return (dt);
    }
}
```